# Oracle Variable name as value oracle

Tags: string, oracle, plsql

I have created some variables. I want to use the variable name as an input of another query. 
Is there any method to get a local variable name as a string value in Oracle.

Example Scenario

```
declare 

FASTFUNDS VARCHAR(100);

begin

FASTFUNDS := 'TEST001';

SELECT v_variable, v_value FROM v_Table WHERE v_variable = FASTFUNDS.toString()
```

**Results**

```
v_variable   v_value

FASTFUNDS      TEST001
```

Comment: What is `v_variable`?  You didn't declare that variable. Where does it come from? And what purpose does `v_table` have?

Comment: You can't simply `SELECT` in PL/SQL - this is not the same as plain SQL. You must `SELECT` **`INTO`** something - most likely **into** `v_variable, v_value` (selecting from columns in the table - it makes no sense to select a program variable from a stored table!)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Java code, so there isn't any `String` type, but `VARCHAR` (as you defined)

Just remove `.toString()` and it'll be a valid statement:

```
SELECT v_variable, v_value FROM v_Table WHERE v_variable = FASTFUNDS;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare 

FASTFUNDS VARCHAR(100);
stmt varchar2(50);
begin

FASTFUNDS := 'TEST001';

stmt := 'SELECT v_variable, v_value FROM v_Table WHERE v_variable = '|| FASTFUNDS;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
end;
```

i dont know your objective, but id do something like this.